# I cant find out why addForce is not working in fixedUpdate. Its working in just normal Update though

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code
it is supposed to make the enemy move backwards and when it hits the box collider it destroys it and adds a point to the score.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class forward : MonoBehaviour
{
    float score;
    public Text text;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.back * 5);
        text.text = "score: " + score;
        print("test");
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
        {
           Destroy(gameObject);
            score = score =+ 1;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is "test" being printed out? If not, `FixedUpdate()` is not being called at all.

Comment: Just an unrelated sidenote: Interesting that a class called **forward** continously adds a force pointing **backwards** ^^

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly why this is happening but the GetComponent should not be called in the update. Also, I think you shouldn't have private in front of FixedUpdate. That may be the problem. It should look like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class forward : MonoBehaviour
{
    float score;
    public Text text;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start(){
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.back * 5);
        text.text = "score: " + score;
        print("test");
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
        {
           Destroy(gameObject);
            score = score =+ 1;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what does this. mean

Comment: "this." might be redundant but is basically the same if you remove it. Usually, you say gameobject.GetComponent<...>() and so you can specify the game object as "this" which is just the game object that this script is attached to.

Comment: I agree with Caleb Sadler about not using GetComponent in update, it was (probably still is) an expensive operation. But this answer will not fix your problem (at least I am pretty sure).

Comment: will the private void FixedUpdate to void FixedUpdate help?

Comment: @CalebSadler no! It makes absolutely no difference. Without a specific accessibility in `c#` everything inside a class is `private` by default anyway. You can make these message methods `private`, `public` or `protected` as much as you like .. it does make no difference at all